# Trying to see if a number in a list is within 1 of its neighbour

Tags: python

I'm trying to compare all the numbers in this list and if any of them are within 1 of the number next to them in the list, if so then I want the command to print True. I realised that by applying the [x+1] to the last item in the list I'd be going out of the range of the list. I've tried to avoid this but I'm still getting the same error. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks :)

```
listed = [2,4,5,7]

for x in listed[:-1]:
        if listed[x+1] - listed[x] == 1:
            print(True)
        else:
            print(False)
```

```
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [155], in <cell line: 3>()
      1 listed = [2,4,5,7]
      3 for x in listed[:-1]:
----> 4         if listed[x+1] - listed[x] == 1:
      5             print(True)
      6         else:

IndexError: list index out of range
```

---

Answer (score 1):

[`itertools.pairwise`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.pairwise) gives you nice neighboring pairs from a list that you can work with:

```
from itertools import pairwise

vals = [x for x in pairwise(listed) if abs(x[0] - x[1]) <= 1]
print(vals)
```

Output:

```
[(4, 5)]
```